# A-frame pool component

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to use the object pooling in a-frame and I can't seem to get it to work. requestEntity() throws an error. Is there an example of how to instantiate objects using the pool component? I may just not have it set up right.

Here's the stripped down a-frame code I'm trying:

```
<a-scene pool__enemyOne="mixin: enemyOne; size: 60; dynamic:true">
<a-assets> 
<a-asset-item id="enemyONE" src="models/enemies/enemy.glb"></a-asset-item>
<a-mixin id="enemyOne" gltf-model="#enemyONE"></a-mixin>
</a-assets>
</a-scene>
```

Here's the JS:

```
var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); 
var EnemyOne = sceneEl.components.pool__enemyOne.requestEntity();
sceneEl.appendChild(EnemyOne);
```

Comment: I recommend sharing full runnable code. Easier to help, know the full context and suggest solutions. Glitch is great https://glitch.com/~aframe Best of luck